# Parallel.For becomes single threaded near the end

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

There is a problem I'm currently experiencing with Parallel.For.
I'm trying to run a batch of ~1000 of pretty long running tasks( each running for like 120 seconds), and my problem seems to be, that on the last 10-20 iterations, the processing becomes single-threaded.

Pseudocode:

```cs
Parallel.For(0, 1000,
           (i, loopState)=> 
           {
            //Do lots of work
            Thread.Sleep(120_000);
           });
```

Do you guys know why this is happening, and how can this issue be fixed?

Comment: How do you know it's becoming single-threaded?

Comment: I've looked at it in Process Explorer. Normally it shows a bunch of threads in the process at 6-8% utilization (8 core CPU), but when this occurs, I can only see a single thread with 12% utilization.

Comment: Use a real profiler.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is meant to distribute work across multiple threads, not to allow precise control over how many threads are used at any given point. It likely has something to do with what sort of work each thread is doing. If it's largely I/O like waiting for some response to return then the answer could be that you're waiting for multiple responses to return and there's nothing for more than one thread to do.

Comment: You could try `Parallel.ForEach` instead of `Parallel.For`. Parallel.ForEach uses dynamic partitioning, which means that partitions are created on the fly as opposed to being allocated in advance. This is good if the workload is imbalanced. In contrast, static partitioning allows elements to be assigned all at once, which results in less overhead, at the cost of not balancing the workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem, or at least found a solution that makes it go away.

Sadly the example code in my question was not 100% representative of my code, in my code I had used the overload with `localInit` and `localFinally`. I thought it didn't matter but It seems it does.

My guess is that in doing so, the internal implementation partitioned up my loop iterations and statically assigned each partition to a separate thread. Since each element took wildly different amount of time to process, it resulted one partition taking a lot longer than the others, hence the single-threading.

The fix was to use the overload that is referenced in my question, which doesn't seem to suffer from this problem.